# JS GET request parse

Tags: javascript, php, curl, get

i'm have a simple page http://mellowkids.ru/serv-ga/test.php with only a Google Analytics Universe code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-44059933-1', 'mellowkids.ru');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

In Chrome Developer Tools i can see what analytics.js generate a js query to http://www.google-analytics.com/collect (gif pixel) with some parameters. 
[image]

Something like this:

```
curl 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j16&a=1674396045&t=pageview
&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fmellowkids.ru%2Fserv-ga%2Ftest.php&ul=ru&de=UTF-8...
```

How i can grab this link (curl) and print it in page by echo or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to need a browser (it can be headless one like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)).

In the case of PhantomJS, through [netlog](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netlog.js), [netsniff](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js) or something similar you will be able to capture the GET request you need (i.e. `http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j16&a=...`) and print it wherever you need.

Comment: I don't understand how use it for my case. Can you write some cod fore it?